# How to retrieve data from multi index table? i a=have stored data dynamically using emplace method now how to get it back as a Record?

Tags: c++

I have used this code to store the data(name and marks) in the table, now i want to retrieve that data in the form of record. how can i get that?

```
void addmarks(account_name examiner, account_name student, uint64_t marks)
    {
        auto toitr = _accounts.find(student);
        if(toitr == _accounts.end())
        {
            _accounts.emplace(examiner, [&](auto& st)
            {
                st.name = student;
                st.obtainedmarks = marks;
            });
        }
        else
        {
            _accounts.modify(toitr,0,[&](auto& st)
            {
                st.obtainedmarks += marks;
                eosio_assert(st.obtainedmarks >= marks, "Marks Assigned");
            });
        } 
    }
```

kindly help me to solve it?

Comment: use find or get, you have already write `auto toitr = _accounts.find(student)`

Comment: yes but it is not working, It returns nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The way to do this with the cl would be to go](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-get-table):

```
cleos get table <contract> <scope> <table>

contract TEXT - The contract who owns the table
scope TEXT - The scope within the contract in which the table is found
table TEXT - The name of the table as specified by the contract abi
```

Example:

```
$ cleos get table eosio.token eosio accounts
{
  "rows": [{
      "balance": "999999920.0000 SYS"
    }
  ],
  "more": false
}
```

Comment: This is working.
Thankyou so much <3